# Form contains a file input, but is missing method=POST

Tags: reactjs, post, spring-boot

I try to upload a file from react to a spring boot server.

Error:

> Form contains a file input, but is missing method=POST and
>   enctype=multipart/form-data on the form.  The file will not be sent.

React code:

```
render() {
          return (

                  <div>
                  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/test-comp">
                      <table>
                          <tr><td>File upload:</td><td><input type="file" name="file" /></td></tr>
                          <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td></tr>
                      </table>
                  </form>
              </div>

          );
      }
```

In spring boot I have a controller that responds to post reques on '/test-comp'.

UPDATE:
used using formMethod and formEncType instead of method and enctype. Alternatively, attach a onSubmit, and now react is sending the request.

Comment: Try using formMethod and formEncType instead of method and enctype. Alternatively, attach a `onSubmit` handler and handle form submission through JavaScript. Right now, your application is going to refresh and you're going to lose the state of your application.

Comment: I changed as you said, it sends the req now to the server but on server side i get error 405: method post not allowed.

Comment: This is something down to your server configuration and nothing related to React. I can't assist further here - sorry.

Comment: Ok, thanks, at least now the request is sent.